# RSpec - Dependant objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm fairly new to testing with RSpec, and have been on this problem for a while.

I have the following test for a user to delete their account.

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'delete account' do
  let!(:user) {create :user, :basic}

  scenario 'successfully' do

    login_as(user)
    visit dashboard_path
    click_link 'Settings'
    click_link 'Cancel my account'

    expect(page).to have_content("Your account has been cancelled.")
  end
end
```

When running the test, I get the following error;

```
1) delete account successfully
 Failure/Error: <%= account.radio_button :plan_id, @plan.id, data: { name: @plan.name, amount: @plan.amount}, checked: true, class: 'hidden' %>

 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the controller code. When the test clicks 'Settings' the show page is rendered. The issue is that no plans exist, but they are irrelevant to what I am testing.

```
def show
  @plan = Plan.find_by(name: 'Premium')
  @subscription_pending_cancel = 
  Account.check_subscription_status(@account)
end
```

I could create the plan before the test runs, which passes the test.

```
 before do
   Plan.create(name: 'Premium')
 end
```

However having to create objects like this doesn't seem sustainable as the test suite grows - particularly in relation to speed and keeping the test DB clean.

The question is - does a real object (being a plan in my case) need to be created/persisted to the db for a test such as the above, or is there another way?

Comment: Share the controller code where do you have this `@plan = Plan.find_by(name: 'Premium')` piece of code

Comment: Have a look at factorygirl.

Comment: I am using Factory girl. In the test I am using it to create the user.

Comment: Can you share the controller code  where you are trying to delete the account?

Comment: Added the controller code - however it's largely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Testing can be done on several levels on "reality", and each of them have their purposes.

You have written an rspec feature spec. These are in the category of so called "acceptance" tests.

The RSpec documentation says:

> Feature specs are high-level tests meant to exercise slices of functionality
>   through an application. They should drive the application only via its external
>   interface, usually web pages.

So point of these test are to be as real as possible, and this also means having as objects as real as possible.

Your observation is correct, there is a lot of setup to be done for these kinds of tests, and they do get quite slow quite fast. And that's why you don't usually write too many of these.

The fast test are in separate category. These are called "unit" test. The point of them is to test only a single class of method, and if there are any dependencies to other classes you should stub them.

These are the kind of tests you should having a lot. And you should drive to write those classes in such a manner that you can easily stub out all the external dependencies (db for example).

This concept is called the testing pyramid. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html